# How would I be able to test a lambda function that is running on AWS locally?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, aws-lambda, pycharm

I am using PyCharm/Ubuntu build and want to test a lambda func that is already deployed to AWS. How would I do that locally? Can the SAM aws cli be used to grab and test the lambda function?

I have been able to only view instances of AWS SAM CLI building lambda function from scratch and running them in a docker container image, but i would like to do tests on a already-deployed lambda function.

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you want to run tests locally (i.e. on your machine) or on AWS lambda platform.  Do you mean manual tests or a particular test suite?  Do you want to run these tests as part of your deployment pipeline?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.